# SQL query takes too long to execute. Need to improve performance of query

Tags: sql, .net, performance, entity-framework

I'm using SQL Server, .NET 5 environment. This SQL query takes too long to execute. This query waiting time is almost 3 min but there are only 35 records. Are there better way to optimize this query ?

```
var allmeetings = await _context.MeetingMaster
                                .Where(x => x.IsActive == true && 
                                            (x.MeetingParticipants.Any(y => y.ParticipantId == Convert.ToInt32(_currentUserService.CurrentUserId)) || 
                                             x.OrganizedById == Convert.ToInt32(_currentUserService.CurrentUserId)))
                                .Include(a => a.MeetingParticipants)
                                .ThenInclude(b => b.Participant)
                                .Include(a => a.MeetingAgendaItems)
                                .ThenInclude(e => e.MeetingActionItems)
                                .ThenInclude(w => w.ActionItemLogs)
                                .Include(a => a.MeetingAgendaItems)
                                .ThenInclude(e => e.MeetingActionItems)
                                .ThenInclude(w => w.ActionItemResposibilities)
                                .Include(g => g.MeetingAgendaItems)
                                .ThenInclude(v => v.MeetingAgendaItemTypes)
                                .ThenInclude(j => j.AgendaItemRef)
                                .Include(w => w.MeetingAgendaItems)
                                .ThenInclude(d => d.RestrictedAgendaItemList)
                                .ThenInclude(s => s.ParticipantRef)
                                .Include(s => s.MeetingAgendaItems)
                                .ThenInclude(q => q.MeetingAgendaItemSupportiveDocuments)
                                .Include(c => c.MonthsRef)
                                .Include(z => z.YearsRef)
                                .Include(g => g.MeetingMinutesDoc)
                                .Include(c => c.Project)
                                .Include(c => c.Category)
                                .Include(l => l.MeetingSuggestions)
                                .Include(q => q.MeetingMattersArises)
                                .ThenInclude(i => i.MattersAriseResponsibilities)
                                .ThenInclude(s => s.ResponsiblePerson)
                                .Include(e => e.MeetingMattersArises)
                                .ThenInclude(w => w.MattersAriseReviewerComments)
                                .Include(s => s.MeetingMattersArises)
                                .ThenInclude(e => e.MattersAriseLogs)
                                .AsSplitQuery()
                                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);

var result = allmeetings.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && 
                                    x.isRecurringMeeting == false && 
                                    (x.MeetingParticipants.Any(y => y.ParticipantId == Convert.ToInt32(_currentUserService.CurrentUserId)) || x.OrganizedById == Convert.ToInt32(_currentUserService.CurrentUserId))).ToList();

var RecMeetings = allmeetings.Where(x => x.IsActive == true && 
                                         x.isRecurringMeeting == true && 
                                         (x.MeetingParticipants.Any(y => y.ParticipantId == Convert.ToInt32(_currentUserService.CurrentUserId)) || x.OrganizedById == Convert.ToInt32(_currentUserService.CurrentUserId))).ToList();

var groupedRecMeetings = RecMeetings.GroupBy(u => u.MeetingRefId.Substring(0, u.MeetingRefId.LastIndexOf('-'))).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();

var GraeterMeetings = new List<MeetingMaster>();
        
foreach (var met in groupedRecMeetings)
{
    result.AddRange(met.FindAll(x => x.MeetingStatus != "Initiated" ));
    GraeterMeetings.AddRange(met.FindAll(x => x.MeetingStatus == "Initiated"));

    if(GraeterMeetings.Count != 0)
    {
        result.Add(GraeterMeetings.OrderBy(x => x.MeetingDate).First());
    }

    GraeterMeetings.Clear();
}

return result.OrderByDescending(d => d.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Please post the exact SQL query that is being run. As presented it's not clear what the filtering condition is (`WHERE`) or what the row ordering is (`ORDER BY`).

Comment: **16 (!!!!)** `.Include` and 14 `.ThenInclude`  - and you're surprised it takes "a long time" to assemble the data!?!?!?!?!

Comment: All those `ToList` probably don't help things either. Why are they there?

Comment: 35 records but possibly 16 + 14 joins?? Do you definitely need all those includes?

Comment: Here its split queries, so 30 seperate queries, all with joins and filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you have so many Includes() and ThenIncludes(), this if really bad for your performance. Is there a way by any chance you can reduce these includes -> only use the necessary one's.

Then i would that you execute the .ToList() query at the end of the statement (befor your return)

Down below is an example how i've done it in the past (with pagination & filtration):

```
            var context = _context.People
                .Include(x => x.Parents)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Adress)
                .Include(x => x.Job)
                .Include(x => x.Hobbies);

            var items = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(query)
                ? context
                : context.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(query));

            var filters = new List<int>();
            if (filter != null)
            {
                filters = filter.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                items = items.Where(x => x.Parents.Select(s => s.AdressId).Any(z => filters.Any(y => y == z)));
            }

            return await items.Skip(page * take).Take(take).ToListAsync();
```